# Error when cross compiling Qt for ARM

Tags: c++, linux, qt, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile Qt on Ubuntu Linux for ARM. But I get the following error:

*bin/rcc: File does not exist 'dialogs/qprintdialog.qrc'*

The build command which produces this is:

**bin/rcc -name qprintdialog dialogs/qprintdialog.qrc -o .rcc/release-shared/qrc_qprintdialog.cpp**

I tried to manually execute this command by giving an absolute path to dialogs/qprintdialog.qrc but still have the same error although dialogs/qprintdialog.qrc does exist.

I have configured Qt as:

./configure -no-exceptions -no-accessibility -no-xsync -no-xinerama -no-xcursor -no-xfixes -no-xrandr -no-xrender -no-mitshm -no-xinput -no-xkb -no-nas-sound -arch arm -platform linux-g++ -xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++  -release -opensource -fast -I$ARM/usr/include -L$ARM/usr/lib -L$ARM/lib -lrt -lX11 -lxcb -lXau -lXdmcp -lXext -lz -prefix custom_path_to_install

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to troobleshot this could be to install Qt Creator. Create a project with your code. Then, don't compile and run inside the IDE, but instead, in your terminal, do to your project folder with all your code (and new Qt Creator file .pro), and enter this:

```
qmake -project
qmake
make
```

Don't change -project, it's really the command, not the name of your project. I believe it will do it. Qt create has a .pro file which is then compile into a Makefile via qmake and manage all that for you.